# 1st Level Page with No Children

Tags: pages, children

I have a website (http://sfa.uconn.edu/) that displays left menu with a list of child pages on any parent page (and its children), like this:

[image]

However, I would like to hide this functionality from top level pages with no children, because it just displays the page title twice, like this:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to test if (1) the current page is top-level and (2) the page has no children.

Comment: For (1): [`get_ancestors( $page->ID, 'page' )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) should return an empty `array` if the page is at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comment:

### Top-level page?  (q.1)

```
global $post;
$x = get_ancestors( $post->ID, 'page' );
if( ! $x ) {
    // there are no ancestors, therefore this is a top-level page
}
```

### Childless page? (q.2)

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'page',
);
$x = get_children( $args );
if( ! $x ) {
    // there are no children
}
```

### References

- [`get_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)
- [`get_children()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children)

**NB** -- this assumes that you're after WordPress's `page`s. If you want a different post type, replace `page` in the code samples with your chose post type's name.